# Most Efficient Way to Get a Single Item Based on Priority Condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have a scenario where there are multiple images within each group and a single image needs to be extracted based on a string criteria.

Below is the way it is done right now, and it works; however, not sure if this is the most efficient way, performance, size, and maybe practice wise too

```
               foreach (var g in groups)
                {
                    SomeType file = null;

                    if (file == null)
                    {
                        file = g.Where(i =>
                                 i.URL.Contains("StringA")
                                 ).FirstOrDefault();
                    }
                    if (file == null)
                    {
                        file = g.Where(i =>
                                  i.URL.Contains("StringB")
                                  ).FirstOrDefault();
                    }
                    if (file == null)
                    {
                        file = g.Where(i =>
                                i.URL.Contains("StringC")
                                ).FirstOrDefault();
                    }
                    if (file == null)
                    {
                       // etc...
                    }
                    if (file == null)
                    {
                        file = g.FirstOrDefault();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Way too broad: code style is off-topic so ignoring that part, size - you obviously can refactor it into a loop (so that is unlikely question you are asking), for performance question - completely missing any numbers and type of LINQ provider you are using...

Comment: There are more efficient ways to do this, but not in LINQ (at least I can't think of a way)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, could you please explain what you mean by LINQ Provider? System.Linq that is the norm and often use MoreLinq library...and it was never about being bored :) I was just never convinced in my approach...I think getting exposed to how other Developers think is awesome!

Comment: Linq-to-object vs. Linq-to-XML vs. Linq-to-SQL vs..... optimizations you can do significantly vary between those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you might find this answer slightly boring but I would avoid trying to find some extremely impressive-looking but complex linq query. I'm sure it could be done but it's not worth the headache.

Just stick all your strings in an array and check them in order of priority. Unless you're running through a large number of items it will be plenty fast enough. You're not executing a db query - your foreach loop makes it clear that your data is already in memory.

So, I'd lose the big if statement and aim for something along the lines of:

```
string [] my_list = new string [] {"StringA", "StringB", "StringC"};

foreach (var g in groups)
{
    foreach (string s in my_list)
    {
        file = g.Where(i => i.URL.Contains(s)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (file != null)
            break;
    }
    if (file == null)
    {
        file = g.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Like I said, not very exciting, but it's dead easy to change your priorities in your search and \ or add and remove strings.

HTH,

Adam.

Comment: I applied this approach and totally surprised by the performance gain! It is also very versatile and allowed me to create different lists based on the app needs and different priorities. Glad I asked!

Answer (score 1):

```
string [] my_list = new string [] {"StringA", "StringB", "StringC"};
foreach (var g in groups)
{
   SomeType file = g.FirstOrDefault(i => my_list.Any(l=>i.Url.Contains(l))) 
                                   ?? g.FirstOrDefault();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] filters = new[] { "StringA", "StringB", "StringC" };

foreach (var g in groups)
{
    SomeType file = filters.Select(s => g.FirstOrDefault(i => i.URL.Contains(s)))
                           .FirstOrDefault(m => m != null);
}
```

Or, if you want to replace the whole loop and actually store the results somewhere:

```
var files = groups.Select(g => filters.Select(s => g.FirstOrDefault(i => i.URL.Contains(s)))
                                      .FirstOrDefault(m => m != null));
```

BTW: An expression like

`file = g.Where(somePredicate).FirstOrDefault();`

can be written as

`file = g.FirstOrDefault(somePredicate);`